# how to log into your discord bot from a React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, discord.js

I'd like to manage a discord bot from my ReactApp. In a separate app I can easily log into my app via

```
const { Client } = Discord

const bot = new Client();

bot.login('token')
```

(the token has been changed)

I'm trying to log from the ReactApp and get a 403 response. I have read that I need to add user-agent, but I don't know how exactly my request should look like.

Comment: I'd recommend regenerating your token. You should never show your token, treat it like a password.

Comment: @Elitezen They said they changed their token.